# How to get items from model class after passing in intent android?

Tags: android, android-intent, model, parcelable

History is a model class which has userName,msgType, rowId.

After getting result, i just passing in list in another activity. How to parse and get each items from History class?

Here is code

```
   public void getHistory(List<History> arg0) {
        intent = new Intent(
                Constants.HISTORY_RESULT);
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.MESSAGE,     (ArrayList<History>) arg0);
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

***in another activity***

 if (action.equals(Constants.HISTORY_RESULT)) {
                onHistory(intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.MESSAGE));
```

}

```
    protected void onHistory(ArrayList<Parcelable> arrayList) {
  // here how to get each items from model class History?

}
```

Comment: You used serializable for passing full model class...

Comment: no. parcelable only.

Comment: please put your parcelable class code.

Comment: this code should work. what your problem with it?

Comment: how to get items from that object arraylist is my question @JiangYD